# Where to put function called by for_each in a class?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

With newer C++ features, you often give a function as a parameter, for example:

```
// File A.cpp    

void do_something(Foo* foo) { ... }

void A::process_foo(){
    for_each( foo_list.begin(), foo_list.end(), do_something );
}
```

But where should I actually put the function `do_something(...)` when I work with classes? I can not make it a private member, since I would loose `this` when passing the parameter to for_each.

So I tend to just define a plain function `do_something(...)` in my implementation file A.cpp, like given in the code above. Since this is visible by the implementation of A only, I do not risk namespace pollution. Since a similiar function in other classes would also only be visible in their implementation, I also do not risk to have a name collision with a similiar function of another class.

Is this the right way?

Another idea would be to use a Lambda. I'm not very familiar with Lambdas, so I don't know whether I should use them as much as possible or only if absolutely necessary...

Comment: Lambdas very easy when you know how. `for_each(foo_list.begin(), foo_list.end(), [](Foo *foo){ foo->something(); });`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a `static` function taking a `Foo *`? That may also be `private` if you want.

Comment: using `std::bind` would permit `do_something` to be private...

Comment: You can put it in an anonymous namespace in the `.cpp` file that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of `std::for_each` needs to be function or function object with one argument such as it may be called with an element of the range defined by first two arguments of `for_each`. Then you have following options (assuming that `foo_list` stores `Foo*`):

**Use regular function**

```
void do_someting(Foo*){...}
for_each(..., do_something);
```

You can put the function wherever it is suitable. If this is for local use, the anonymous namespace is the best option. But it may be e.g. defined in a separate compilation unit.

**Use static method**

```
static void do_something(Foo*){...}
for_each(..., &Foo::do_something);
```

Note that it does not need necessarily to be static method of `Foo`.

**Use lambda**

```
for_each(...,[](Foo* f){...});
```

**Use a method** of Foo class (even private) and **`std::bind`**

```
void method(){...}
for_each(..., std::bind(&Foo::method, _1));
```

There are other options but those are the most common.

Comment: Anonymous namespace = namespace of function put in my .cpp file with no further namespace specification?

Comment: Anonymous namespace == `namespace { <function goes here> }` normally in .cpp

Answer (score 1):

**C++11 solution**

If you can use C++11, prefer range-based for instead of `std::for_each` and just write code in-place. Like this:

```
for (const auto& value : foo_list)
{ 
  // do something with the value
}
```

It is less verbose and more convenient. It iterates through all of the elements one by one, just like `std::for_each` algorithm. And you can explicitly specify that you don't want to modify elements by putting `const auto&`, or simply `auto` (without reference).

**Partial-C++11**

If your compiler has no support of range-based fors, but has support of lambdas (like Visual Studio 2010), simply put function into lambda:

```
for_each( foo_list.begin(), foo_list.end(), 
  [] (const FooList::value_type& value) { /* do something with the value */; });
```

**C++98**

If you can use none of the above C++11 features, most of STL algorithms look pathetic. Whichever you place `do_something` function to, it will be decoupled from the calling code, which is very hard to read. Prefer simple iterator-based for in this case:

```
for (FooList::iterator pValue = foo_list.begin(); pValue != foo_list.end(); ++pValue) 
{ 
  // do something with the pValue
}
```

**PS** I prefer the latter form even for "Partial-C++11" case, when you cannot use range-based fors, but can replace `FooList::iterator` with simple `auto`. It is very helpful when you would have to write something more complicated, like `std::list<std::string>::const_iterator`. I think the following is better than `std::for_each` with lambda:

```
for (auto pValue = foo_list.begin(); pValue != foo_list.end(); ++pValue) 
{ 
  // do something with the pValue
}
```

Comment: This is an elaborate answer, but to another question ;-) I'm not primarily asking about how to iterate over a a vector, but where to actually put a function that is taken by something like for_each(...). But thanks anyway, it gives some good ideas about how to iterate over a vector.

Comment: @Michael Hm, ok, whatever :)